# Does asp.net MVC need to be compiled before it’s deployed onto a web server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can’t get a basic MVC site to work on my web server unless I’ve compiled it first in Visual Web Developer. If it doesn’t have a dll in the Bin, it says the Namespace can’t be found.

In classic asp.net I could just upload the files and the server would compile it at first run. Is this not the case in MVC? Essentially I’d like to build an MVC site without using Visual Web Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cause ASP.NET MVC is not based on the Website model that many ASP.NET Web Forms apps were. It is based on the Web application model.

You can [read about Web Application Projects here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx).

I've read about people [migrating the Web Application to the Web site model in ASP.NET MVC](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/15/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx) but I don't recommended it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to compile an MVC site and deploy some DLLs in a bin folder when you deploy an MVC site

You can build MVC without Visual web developer...  but why?